# Reveal.js not working with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, reveal.js

I have a demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/qYKpM/) (jsfiddle)...

I can't figure out why this isn't working in this fiddle. According to the documentation **[here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html)**, this is all I need for the AJAX request...

```
<a href="http://some-url" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">
    Click Me For A Modal
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, one can't run your demo because the jquery.reveal.js script is hosted on a server which requires authentication.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js : "At the end of your page you need to initialize reveal by running the following code. Note that all config values are optional and will default as specified below. [...]"

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. There's nothing in that documentation that says I need that configuration for ajax requests... just html builds.

Comment: Try doing it and running it with my fiddle. It's not going to work.

Comment: @webfrogs well . That's not the good reveal lib.  Looks like the one you use has been integrated into the fundation framework.

Comment: Can you write a working fiddle so I can better understand your meaning?

Comment: @webfrogs my googlefoo found this page http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin ; it introduces the plugin without the foundation thing. And all in all, you did what the author said.

Comment: I found that too... I can get the modal to work, but for my needs, I need the ajax requests to work. This modal has to go on multiple pages, and the less code I have to write on these multiple pages, the better.

Comment: @webfrogs then you need the last version and you have to go through the whole foundation initialization process, as far as I can tell. See http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/, especially the "HTML Page Markup" section.